# How to query a database that matches a specific name in a foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, gridview

I have two tables in my database Student and Subject. And I made a relationship between the StudentID(primary key for student)and a foreign key for the subject.

Here's the list of data for my Subject:
[image]

How do I select all the data that matches the foreign key(StudentID for Subject) example : 2011017997 to display the courseno,coursedecription,units,day,starttime and so on.

I want to use session to display my subject data as a Gridview in the next page.

this is my aspx code behind:

```
    string query = null;
    string subjectquery = null;
    int rowcounter = 0;
    private DataSet studentData;
    private DataSet subjectData;
    private DataTable subjectTable;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Connection String
        connector.ConnectionString = "Data Source=keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True";

        //String decleration
        string username = (this.UserName.Value);
        string pass = (this.Password.Value);

        //query database from sql server management studio for student
        query = "select studentid,password,firstname,lastname,course,year from student";

        //query database from sql server management studio for subject
        subjectquery = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room from subject";

        //execute query for student
        studentData = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);

        //execute query for subject
        subjectData = connector.ExecuteQuery(subjectquery);


        for (;;)
        {
            //string decleration and getting each rows of the Student database
            string userid = studentData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["StudentID"].ToString();
            string password = studentData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["Password"].ToString();
            string firstname = studentData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["FirstName"].ToString();
            string lastname = studentData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["LastName"].ToString();
            string course = studentData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["Course"].ToString();
            string year = studentData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["Year"].ToString();

            //get all subject data rows and store it into DataTable
            subjectTable = subjectData.Tables[0];

            //Username and Password are correct
            if ((username == userid) && (pass == password))
            {
                Session["login"] = userid;
                Session["firstname"] = firstname;
                Session["lastname"] = lastname;
                Session["course"] = course;
                Session["year"] = year;
                Session["Subjects"] = subjectTable;
                Response.Redirect("StudentPage.aspx", true);
                break;
            }
            //empty username and password
            else if (((username == "") && (pass == "")) || ((userid == null) && (password == null)))
            {
                Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password must have input value. Try again');</script>");
                break;
            }
            //username is invalid and password is correct ; username is correct and password is invalid
            else if (((username != userid) && (pass == password)) || ((username == userid) && (pass != password)))
            {
                Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again');</script>");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                rowcounter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

When the program display the results all the data of the subject is display but not the data of the studentID "2011017997".

I think my problem is the query, this:

```
//query database from sql server management studio for subject
            subjectquery = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room from subject";
```

and this is how I display my DataTable in Session:

```
//execute query for subject
            subjectData = connector.ExecuteQuery(subjectquery);
//get all subject data rows and store it into DataTable
                subjectTable = subjectData.Tables[0];
Session["Subjects"] = subjectTable;
```

The code for displaying the subject data using GridView in another page:

```
//Subject Data
                subjectdata.DataSource = Session["Subjects"];
                subjectdata.DataBind();
```

How do I compare or something to just display the followings subjects that matches the following StudentID = 2011017997?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this !

```
subjectquery = "select * from subject where StudentID=2011017997";
```

Comment: This is one is good but it will display all the column name including the studentid and teacherid.

I've come up with something like this:
subjectquery = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room from subject where studentid = 2011017997";

Comment: yes, select * means to display all columns from the table, you can change it to your like. Hope my answer helped you !

Answer (score 0):

My question, My answer? haha anyways here's the correct query for my problem. Thanks for the Idea @boyshot17.

```
//Get the value for input username
string username = (this.UserName.Value);

//query database from sql server management studio for subject
subjectquery = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room from subject where studentid = " + username + "";
```